# CAS integration with IdentityServer3 (as an Open Id Connect client)

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, cas, openid-connect, identityserver3

I'm trying to integrate CAS server with IdentityServer3 (CAS acting as a Open ID Client).

Following the guides, I updated the cas.properties and changed the following:
```

```
cas.pac4j.oidc.id=clientid
cas.pac4j.oidc.secret=secret
cas.pac4j.oidc.discoveryUri=https://IdentityServer3/.well-known/openid-configuration
```

```

I also update the pom.xml file and added **pac4j-oidc** dependency (not sure if it was needed but it was missing initially)

Now when I access the CAS login page I can see the **Oidc** long link but the URL is invalid:
https://localhost:8433/cas/login?client_name=OidcClient&needs_client_redirection=true

**I was expecting to automatically discover the IdentityServer URL from the discovery document. Is there anything else I need to do?**

I also tried adding the following bean to the pac4jContext.xml file:
```

```
<bean id="oidc1" class="org.pac4j.oidc.client.OidcClient">
        <property name="id" value="clientid" />
        <property name="secret" value="secret" />
        <property name="discoveryUri" value="https://IdentityServer3/.well-known/openid-configuration" />
    </bean>
```

```

When I do this the CAS server is not working anymore (I get a 404 when trying to access it via Tomcat)

Java is not my first language so I'm not sure if I'm missing something obvious but I would really appreciate some help with this.

Comment: You might want to reach out to the pac4j community and report the error. Jérôme is usually very quick to respond.